# Dart serialize object with integer list

Tags: dart

I have

```
Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {"languageCode": languageCode, "mIds": mIds};
```

but mIds is list of integer.

When I try to send the `dto.toMap()` in the body of the post
it says:

> Exception has occurred.
> _TypeError (type 'List' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast)

What is the correct way of serializind dto with list of int?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```dart
Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => 
  {"languageCode": languageCode, "mIds": mIds.map((id) => id.toString()).toList()};
```

Comment: Unfortunatele: _TypeError (type 'List<String>' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast)

Comment: Please add data sample.

Comment: It looks like your `mIds` is String @JaczuraZoltán

Comment: `"0: languageCode" :"hu_HU"
1:
"mIds" :
[0]: "1001"
[1]: "1002"`

Comment: If I use:  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {"languageCode": languageCode, "mIds": mIds.map((id) => id).toList()};

It says: _TypeError (type 'List<int>' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast)

So I am sure mIds is not mapped  right.